# Add first element of Map into another list at 1st Position and so on...second map element into second position of list

Tags: java

```
**Here We have product bean. There is some attributes like productname,tax and ..etc.             ** 
Product product = new Product();
product.setProductName("Laptop");

Product product1 = new Product();
product1.setProductName("Mobile");
List<Product> productList = Arrays.asList(product, product1);
**Created Map of Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>**
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> productCart = new HashMap<String, List<Map<String, String>>>();
List<Map<String, String>> listTax1 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
List<Map<String, String>> listTax2 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("XR", "123");
map1.put("TAX", "234");
map1.put("SURCHARGE", "567");
listTax1.add(map1);

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map2.put("XR", "1234");
map2.put("TAX", "2345");
map2.put("SURCHARGE", "5678");
listTax2.add(map2);

productCart.put("1", listTax1);
productCart.put("2", listTax2);
```

**//
 I want to add productCart into productList one by one.//**
**Add first element of Map into another list at 1st Position and so on...second map element into second position of list.**

> Try with Java 8

Comment: `HashMap` has no guarantee of order - in fact ` it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.`  so if you're ok with this then simply loop on the keyset.

Comment: if you want the entries in map to be in order of insertion, you'll have to use `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: yes, try to use LinkedHashMap.

Comment: **ok, I will change to #LinkedHashMap from HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you can use this one -**

```
int j=0;
for(int i=0;i<productList.size();i++) {
    Product productData=  productList.get(i);
    List keys =new ArrayList(productCart.keySet());
    while(j<=i) {
        Object listKeys=  keys.get(i);
        List<Map<String, String>> pro=productCart.get(listKeys);
        for (Map<String, String> map : pro) {
                map.forEach((k,v)-> {
                   //Write Yours Conditions 
                    if(k.equalsIgnoreCase("SURCHARGE")){
                    }
                });

        }
        j++;
    }

}
```